# Adding a table to main viewcontroller, but getting a memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image: I'm not sure what this indicates but, any help would be awesome.]

Here's code from the mainviewcontroller

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController
{
    NSArray *toDoList;
}

@synthesize menuBtn;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //initialize table data
    toDoList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apples", "Bananas", "Soda", nil];
```

...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [toDoList count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ToDoList";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [toDoList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

From sliding view controller

```
- (void)setTopViewController:(UIViewController *)theTopViewController
{
  CGRect topViewFrame = _topViewController ? _topViewController.view.frame : self.view.bounds;

  [self removeTopViewSnapshot];
  [_topViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
  [_topViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
  [_topViewController removeFromParentViewController];

  _topViewController = theTopViewController;

  [self addChildViewController:self.topViewController];
  [self.topViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

  [_topViewController.view setAutoresizingMask:self.autoResizeToFillScreen];
  [_topViewController.view setFrame:topViewFrame];
  _topViewController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
  _topViewController.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.layer.bounds].CGPath;

  [self.view addSubview:_topViewController.view];
}
```

initViewController..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
  }
```

And main.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks a lot more like a crash to me.

Comment: That error is not a memory leak. That error usually means you're accessing a deallocated object. You should set an exception breakpoint to your app to see where it's crashing.

Comment: @rdelmar yeah the code i pasted above includes are the breakpoints that ID where the exception is being thrown

Comment: Did you write all required methods of TableView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crash is being caused by the following line of code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
toDoList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apples", "Bananas", "Soda", nil];
```

You are trying to add an `NSString` and two C strings. Try this:

```
toDoList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apples", @"Bananas", @"Soda", nil];
```

I'm surprised there isn't a compiler warning on this line of code. Never ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: Oh wow. It took me like 5 minutes to figure out the difference between your code and mine. I either need coffee or sleep. Thanks.